# Weakening Sobolev coefficient in an elliptic estimate.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-operators

One of the classical estimates for Sobolev norms and elliptic operators is the following: let $L$ be an elliptic operator of order $l$, then there is some $C > 0$ such that for all $u \in H^{s+l}$ ($C$ probably depends on $s$) such that we have an estimate of the form

$$\|u\|_{s+l} \leq C(\|u\|_s + \|Lu\|_s)$$

My question is whether the coefficient $s$ on $\|u\|_s$ can be weakened over compact Riemannian manifolds. The question is motivated by a result that we can find a pseudo-differential operator $S$ of order $-l$ such that $SL - I = K$ continuously maps compactly supported distributions to smooth functions.

This would seem to imply we can prove a form of the above estimate by writing

$$u = SLu - Ku$$

Then using the continuity of inclusions $H^r \to \mathcal{E}' = \mathcal{D}'$ (compactness of $M$ key here) and $C^\infty \to H^{s+l}$ to bound the latter term, and the operator norm of $S$ to bound the former. This seems disturbing to me as it would imply we just need *any* information on a Sobolev norm of $u$, not the $s$ norm in particular.

Comment: Thinking about it a little bit more, I think this just follows from a bootstrapping argument with the original estimate as for example we can apply it twice get a bound:
$$\|u\|_{s+l} \leq C_1(C_2(\|u\|_{s-l} + \|Lu\|_{s-l}) + \|Lu\|_s)$$
And then use that $\|Lu\|_{s-l} \leq \|Lu\|_s$ to rewrite with some new constant 
$$\|u\|_{s+l} \leq C(\|u\|_{s-l} + \|Lu\|_s)$$

Comment: Looks good to me. I don't think it should seem disturbing; for example, a common simple statement of elliptic regularity is that if $u$ is a "weak solution" to $Lu = f$ and $f$ is smooth, then $u$ is smooth. I think that $u$ can be in any Sobolev space to apply this.

Comment: @JHance I have deleted the copy of this on MO. I guess I'm curious as to whether or not there is a way to seeing this from some sort of Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality.